# QString numbers stay the same in serial communication

Tags: c++, qt, arduino

I have trouble with reading serial data from an Arduino, and sending it to the UI. I found it to be a hassle to split all serial data into 3 seperate variables, and therefore used the left and mid to get the specific numbers. The problem now is that the numbers I get stays the same, eventhough I can see on an LCD display they change.
This is a section of the code:

```
void Dolle::serialReceived(){
  ba = serial->readAll();

  serialBuffer += QString::fromStdString(ba.toStdString());  

  QString bufferSplit = serialBuffer;

  QString hum = bufferSplit.left(2);
  QString temp = bufferSplit.mid(2, 2);
  QString gas = bufferSplit.mid(4, 4);

  if((hum.size()==2) && (temp.size()==2) && (gas.size()==4)){
    ui->humLabel->setText("Humidity:        "+hum+" %");
    ui->tempLabel->setText("Temperature:   "+temp+(char(176))+ "C");
    ui->gasLabel->setText("Gas level:         "+gas);
    qDebug() << hum << temp << gas;
  }
}
```

Comment: You append data to your buffer, but you read the data from the same position and set that to your labels. Are you sure it shouldn't just be `serialBuffer = QString::fromStdString(ba.toStdString());`? Also the `stdString` conversion seems unnecessary.

Comment: I did this because the numbers flowing out in the terminal were without any order and just randomly put together. Also the ba is a QByteArray, and thats why I thought the conversion was a necessary.

Comment: Well either way, you are just reading the same data from `serialBuffer` over and over again.

Comment: Oh okay, I tried removing the + sign but then it didn't print anything. Do you know how I can get around the problem of it reading the same number?

Comment: Ah, so the data is split. You need to check how much data is received. Once you have all the data, then you proceed to write it to your labels. You can append it to the buffer like you are currently doing. But once the buffer's size is what you expect it to be, read that data from the buffer, and remove it from the buffer, so you won't read the same data again.

Comment: Should I just use .clear(); to get new data in then ?

Comment: It's probably not that simple. You could have more data in the buffer than you are going to use. For example, you might expect `x` bytes of data, but when you read it from the socket, you might get `x + 12` bytes. You don't want to discard these 12 bytes of data. You only want to remove the `x` bytes from the buffer that you already read and used to display on the labels.

Comment: I made an if(bufferSplit.size()>7), and have tried a both push.back and a clear(); but none have worked so far.

Comment: What about something like `if(bufferSplit.size() >= expected_size) serialBuffer.remove(0, expected_size);`. You can also check the `serialBuffer` size before reading it into `bufferSplit`. Then if the size is as big or bigger than expected, do `bufferSplit = serialBuffer.left(expected_size);`, and then remove the first `expected_bytes` from `serialBuffer`.

Comment: Thanks so much, it works perfectly now! How do I mark as solved?

Comment: @giggitygoat "How do I mark as solved?" You don't :) Someone, including yourself, might write an answer to the question, but it no case should you modify the question itself to reflect that. If an answer solves your problem, you can mark it as accepted.

Comment: @thuga You could post your last comment as an answer, so I can accept it.

Comment: You can accept Kuba's answer. It covers all the things I mentioned and more.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several problems:

1. You're appending to `serialBuffer`, but you never empty it out. The `QIODevice` already maintains an internal, resizable circular buffer for you, so a second one is not necessary.
2. You're going from binary representation to a `QString` via a `std::string`. That is completely unnecessary.
3. You're not explicit about what character encoding is used in the binary data.
4. The UI is updated repeatedly, instead of at most once per `readyRead` signal.
5. You're using magic constants. You should UTF-8 encode your source instead, or use a named `QChar` constant.
6. You're manually building strings using string operators, this impedes internationalization and maintainability.
7. You're using spaces as a mechanism to align the display in your UI. Perhaps you should design your UI in a different manner, so that such hacks won't be necessary.

I presume that your strings are separated somehow - perhaps each is in a separate line? In any case, you should keep reading the complete delimited strings from the device as long as they are available. The `QIODevice::readLine` method makes it easy in case of line-delimited data:

```
void Dolle::serialReceived() {
  QString validLine;
  while (serial->canReadLine()) {
    auto binLine = serial->readLine();
    auto line = QString::fromLatin1(binLine);
    if (line.length() < 8)
      continue;
    validLine = line;
  }
  if (validLine.isEmpty()) return;
  auto hum = line.left(2);
  auto temp = line.mid(2, 2);
  auto gas = line.mid(4, 4);
  ui->humLabel->setText(QStringLiteral("Humidity: %1%").arg(hum));
  ui->tempLabel->setText(QStringLiteral("Temperature: %1°C").arg(temp));
  ui->gasLabel->setText(QStringLiteral("Gas level: %1").arg(gas));
}
```

Suppose that instead of line-separated data, your data arrives in fixed-size chunks. You'd process them in a similar fashion:

```
void Dolle::serialReceived() {
  QString validPacket;
  while (serial->bytesAvailable() >= 8) {
    auto bin = serial->read(8);
    auto packet = QString::fromLatin1(bin);
    if (packet.length() < 8)
      continue;
    validPacket = packet;
  }
  ...
}
```